# remove a file from working directory and them commit compared to use git rm

Tags: git

I'm reading a Git book, it says:

**To remove a file from Git, you have to remove it from your tracked files (more accurately, remove it from your staging area) and then commit. The "git rm" command does that**

but I think I can also achieve the same thing in this way, let's say I need to remove a text file called `abc.txt`:
Firstly, I delete the `abc.txt`.
Secondly, I use:

> git add abc.txt

and then

> git commit -m "remove abc.txt"

isn't that the same thing as use `git rm`?

Another question I have is, I have manually deleted `abc.txt`, so it doesn't exist on the hard disk anymore, how still I can issue "git add abc.txt" as the file still exist?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [git add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add), and especially the bits about removed files?

Comment: "remove it from your staging area" is not more accurate than "remove it from your tracked files". "Staging area" is what misleads.  The index is an index, a list of pointers to interesting content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that the two-command sequence:

```
rm abc.txt
git add abc.txt
```

removes `abc.txt` from the index / staging-area.  The first command removes `abc.txt` from the work-tree; the second tells Git to look at the removal in the work-tree, and apply the same change in the index / staging-area.

The book suggests using:

```
git rm abc.txt
```

which removes `abc.txt` from the index / staging-area *and* from the work-tree in one step.  These do produce the same result, but the book's recommendation does it with fewer commands, and perhaps less confusion.

---

> [now that I] have manually deleted `abc.txt`, so it doesn't exist on the hard disk anymore, how still I can issue "git add abc.txt" as [if] the file still exists?

This might be a little confusing because of the word *add*, but in fact, this `add` verb doesn't necessarily mean *add* at all.  It just tells Git to use whatever is in the work-tree—or in this case, the *lack* of something in the work-tree—to *update* something in the index / staging-area.

The people who wrote the code that implements the `git add` command *could* have implemented it so that it just produced an error message here.  Then you would be forced to use `git rm` or similar.  But they could, in their code, inspect the work-tree and see that the file `abc.txt` no longer exists.  They can then translate that, internally, into a request to *delete* `abc.txt` from the index / staging-area.  And that's exactly what they did do.

Note that when a file exists in the index / staging-area, and you use `git add` from the command line, this directs Git to *replace* the index / staging-area copy with an updated version from the work-tree.  So that, too, does not *add a new file*, it just replaces an existing one.

Many Git commands today behave the way they do as a result of long experience with things that were mistakes more than ten years ago.  Some of those mistakes must be, and still are, preserved for backwards-compatibility.  Others were fixable and have been fixed, either by adding new commands, or by tweaking commands so that they do somewhat odd things at times.  A rare few required changing the major version number of Git, from 1.x to 2.x.  In this particular case, *add* can mean *remove*.  In fact, this behavior is more consistent now, in Git 2.x, than it was in 1.x, which is why `git add` has the flag `--ignore-removal`.  See [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) for details.

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation of removing a file with `git add`

Adding a removed file seems backwards at first - here's the explanation.

The `git add` command adds any *changes* to files from the **working directory** into the **index**, so that they are ready to be committed. It doesn't add *files* to the repo directly, which is confusing when first using git.

So, it doesn't matter if those changes are a new file, changes to an existing file, or even the removal of a file, `git add` is just preparing them to be added to the repo by moving them into the commit staging area, the index.

Use an overview image on the different transfers that occur in git something like the following (pulled from Google images). The blue `add` arrow shows moving changes between workspace and index.
[image: Git file storage areas and commands to move between them]

Answer (score 0):

To remove a file from Git you can:

- Either: `git rm filename`
- Or: `rm filename && git add filename` (or even easier: `rm filename && git add -u`)

They'll do the same thing.